# scroll to specific div using webview in react native

Tags: react-native, uiwebview

In the web browser, we can add a scroll by mentioning the location of the div by doing www.example.com/#mydiv

**Context:** 
I am rendering a webpage using a webview in react native. So there is a link in the page itself that makes the url pointing to that div. It would be www.example.com/#mydiv

In the normal web browser it works as expected but how the same functionality can be achieved using WebView in react native such that the user clicks on that link and the page scrolls to that div. Following is my code for Web View.

```js
<WebView
  source={{uri: BASE_URL}}
  style={styles.container}
  onLoadStart={() => this.showSpinner()}
  onLoadEnd={() => this.hideSpinner()}
  onError={() => this.errorInLoading()}
  ref={this.state.webViewRef}
  javaScriptEnabled={true}
  domStorageEnabled={true}
  geolocationEnabled={true}
  cacheEnabled={true}
 />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the injectJavaScript parameter of WebView, to show exactly what you want from the destination web.

[WebView documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#injectjavascript)

Comment: It means that I need to register click events separately through the `injectedJavascript` method where ever I need to do this kind of web functionality( scrolling to a specific div on the web page). My question is that the embedded website already has those click events so why do I need to inject them again? Though they do not work on the react native webview some how.